# Android: enumerate available pixel formats for window or set the best available

Tags: android, compatibility, gradient, pixelformat

I want to use a gradient background for my activities. There are many question here reagrding this topic, with solutios like turning on dithering, setting the pixel format to RGBA_8888 or RGB_565.

I tried both. My phone doesn't support RGBA_8888, and RGB_565 works, but on more advanced displays (even on the emulator), it may look uglier. I want to support every screen, and set the pixel format as high as possible.

However, I did not find any methods to enumerate the supported types. The documentation of setFormat says that the value UNKNOWN makes the system choose a format based on the decorations the window uses. What are these? How can I maximize the quality while still being compatible with lower-category screens?

Thank you.